# Плохая масштабируемость сайта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css

У меня есть сайт полностью адаптированный под мобильные устройства, но есть одна проблема, при открытии сайта на телефоне он как бы увеличен, а чтобы увидеть его в обычном состоянии, нужно его отдалить.

Это выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полная версия выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, что проблема в стилях блоков ограничителей.

```
.wrapper {
    min-width: 1400px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1700px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Структура html примерно такая:

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <section class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="header__header">
                    Reptile - nursery with snakes, lizards, and other cold-blooded.
                </h1>
                <p>content content content content content content </p>
                <button class="header__button">Learn more</button>
            </div>
        </section>
</div>
```

Но в то же время, если убрать стили ограничивающих блоков, сайт адекватно не масштабируется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Чтобы что-то масштабировалось нужно все размеры указывать в %, vw, vh

Comment: У вас на мобильной версии тесты не помещаются в ширину отведённую им разрешением сотового телефона. Сами задумайтесь, если текст настолько огромный, что занимает 700px в ширину, как он поместится в сотовый, который 600px? Или вы думали что тексты, изображения автоматически уменьшаются в зависимости от размера экрана? Вон в последней фотке вашей, слово recommendations явно выходит за рамки дозволенного. Нужно писать типа @media (max-width: 767px) {и тут уменьшаем размер текста}. Обычно когда верстаешь, тебе дизайнер даёт и мобильную версию, а на ней текст совсем другого размера.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что вы забыли добавить [meta-тег viewport](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/metateg-viewport-pochemu-on-vazhen-i-kak-ego-pravilno-ispolzovat), из-за чего вы неправильно интерпретировали поведение мобильника (без viewport мобильник пытается отрисовать сайт как компьютерный сайт), сделали из этого неверные выводы и сверстали всё в неправильных размерах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите адаптировать сайт для мобильных устройств, то вам не следует настолько жёстко устанавливать ширину контейнеров. На данный момент ваш сайт не может быть меньше 1400px, что значительно превышает размер мобильного устройства, что и следует из его поведения на малых экранах. Позвольте *.wrapper* занимать все доступное пространство:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

А вот *.container* можно задать ограничения:

```
.container {
  max-width: 1700px;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Если убрать стили у wrapper, и оставить только width: 100%; то при сужении экрана примерно до 730px появляется серая область справа, как показано на последней картинке

Comment: @Salivan, все верно, т.к. у вас, как и указывали выше в комментария, слишком большой шрифт для мобильного устройства. Таким образом вам необходимо либо использовать медиа запрос для изменения размера шрифта, либо задавать шрифт в относительных единицах, либо с использованием функции calc() рассчитывать шрифт в зависимости от размера экрана.